# Creating wordcloud with greek symbols

Tags: r, word-cloud, r-highcharter

Is it possible to create a wordcloud with greek symbols? Since `expression` is not working within a data frame, is there a workaround?

Here is a small example what I'm trying to do, but haven't figured out how the cloud could show the symbols instead.

```
library(highcharter)

hchart(data.frame(greek_symbols = c("beta","mu","gamma")), "wordcloud", hcaes(name = greek_symbols, weight = rep(1,1,1)))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If youir input is given by the written names of the symbols you could make a translation vector as in your cloud you want to provide the unicode value of the symbol. `symbols_conversion` should include all (I just added yours plus one). So `symbols_to_show` contains the names you want to display. Subset like `symbols_conversion[symbols_to_show]` to get the symbols shown.

```
library(highcharter)

symbols_conversion <- c("beta" = "\u03b2", "gamma" = "\u03b3", "delta" = "\u03b4", "mu" = "\u03bc")
symbols_to_show <- c("beta","mu","gamma")

hchart(data.frame(greek_symbols = symbols_conversion[symbols_to_show]), "wordcloud", hcaes(name = greek_symbols, weight = rep(1,1,1)))
```

[image]